# Populate Google Spreadsheet from Form using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I create a Google Spreadsheet and a Google Form via the Google App Script and want to get all the responses from the form automatically added to a sheet in my spreadsheet.

This option is possible if you do it manually, but I can't find an option to do it automatically in Google App Script.

I have seen some answers here on StackOverflow to populate forms from spreadsheets, but I need the inverse case.

Is that possible?

Comment: Usually we create a form by clicking on tools > Creat a form inside the spreadsheet. That way, the form is automatically bound to your sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Form.setDestination()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setdestinationtype,-id), like this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Response destination spreadsheet');
const form = FormApp
  .create('New form name')
  .setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms has a setting that allows you to send your form responses to Google Sheets. This can be a new or existing spreadsheet.

In your chosen form, click on the responses tab.

- Click on the three dots button located next to the Google Sheets icon.
- Click on Select responses destination from the drop.
- Select existing spreadsheet.

If you want to do it by script, as the form is already created

```
var form = FormApp.openById('id of the form');
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, 'id of the spreadsheet);
```

[destination type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type)

Comment: Yes. But I'm looking for a way to do that automatically in Google App Script.

Comment: Answer updated!